# Remove excessive nodes of a SVG path for iPad

Tags: vector, path, software-recommendation, ipad, path-effects

Can you please suggest an app for iPad that simplifies path by reduction of excessive nodes of vector path?

I would need something like this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PC4mPfwAX2s

If not an app, maybe an online tool. I have tried Inkscape but I am not happy with the results. Inkscape reduces to many points at once and there is no way to customize it.

Comment: FWIW - the plug-in in that video was for illustrator on a desktop: one of  Astute Graphics plug-ins. That said - A) iPad focussed - not illustrator-based workflows therefore - maybe Affinity Designer - there isn't the huge ecosystem of plug-ins for Affinity Designer as of yet, both due to it being as new to market as it is, and because thus far Affinity hasn't seen fit to publish an API for Designer plug-ins - they've done this and set Affnity Photo to use Photoshop plugins, but last time I checked, they didn't feel Illustrator plug-in compatibility was high priority B) I'd say do it manually.

Comment: @GerardFalla and i feel like not releasing an API is a sign of internal design weakness of the code base. The api is free only reason not to release one is sign that the code is not doing well. Same goes for scripting support. Photoshop plugins have a stable ABI illustrator does not so you wont see illustrator compatible plugins